# Create installation for a CMS using Codeigniter 2.0.3

Tags: codeigniter, content-management-system, codeigniter-2, web-platform-installer

I have created a basic CMS using CodeIgniter 2.0.3, and now I want to create an installation so it can work on other computers. I have hard time finding any advice on the net. What is the best practice in this case?

Comment: always want to put the EXACT version number not 'latest version' as time passes, and people might have the same question or might be confused WHICH version it is, you might even come back and not recall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for an example, download and review [ionize cms](http://www.ionizecms.com/). It has a good installer and is released under the Open Source MIT license.

Comment: This kinda helps a lot :). Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

The [Ionize CMS](http://ionizecms.com) installer is a good start, but remember it is written only to install Ionize, not for other purposes.
Anyway, it can help you to discover how to load CI classes and use them "outside" of CI.